# empty mysql database with relation exists

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to reset my database through phpmyadmin ,but its not working because relation exists in other tables.

i am in dev phase and i want to clear all my table records .

What will be the best way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: export your database structure(including tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one solution would be to export the database structure from within phpMyAdmin (of course you can also do this through your console/terminal), then drop the entire database and then recreate it from the exported file.

Comment: you'll still get an exception when trying to run a mysql command using the dump if foreign keys are duplicates

Comment: looks like better one ,i also need to set  a option `Reset Project` which will delete all the records ..

Comment: Of course you should only export the actual structure of the database and not the data it contains=)

Answer (score 2):

remove all tables index ( except primary key ) and then truncate all the tables.

if there are Foriegn key contraints on tables then first remove relation from child table
and then remove index from parent table

Comment: I dont want to play with its structure , it may break the codes.

Comment: Ya, I run into this problem with WordPress all of the time... for whatever reason, some plugins sneak in duplicate entries and your gonna have foreign key issues... modify your tables to exclude the foreign keys then truncate as Ezequiel said... then you can reset your keys

Comment: The right way to do this is to first truncate the child tables, then the parent tables. This inherently requires knowledge of the db architecture, and may still not work if there is a constraint loop.